How do I get breakdown of COGS?
Is there a way to get a breakdown of COGS for a public company?


In general, no.  For specific companies, you can look at their annual report to shareholders and see if they provide a breakdown by whatever you want it broken down by.

Companies often provide a very high-level summary in the actual financial statements, but may offer "notes" in their annual or quarterly reports to break down items even further depending on investor and/or analyst demand. Generally you can search the PDF for key words (e.g. "Cost of Sales") to look for notes related to specific line items, or they may add a footnote that references a note to the statement.
If they do not break it down in the statement or notes there is probably no way to get it. Companies generally only provide as much detail as investors or analysts ask them to.
